# How to access the value of a dictionary faster from a list of arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I was wondering how can I access the value of a dictionary rapidly from a list of arrays.

Here is my toy example:

```
my_list = [np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10]), np.array([ 1,  3,  5,  6,  7, 10]), np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  8,  9, 10]), np.array([ 1,  3,  4,  7, 15]), np.array([ 1,  2,  4,  5, 10, 16]), np.array([6, 10, 15])]

my_dict = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 3, 16: 3}
```

Each key in **my_dict** correspond to the values in a list named **my_list**

I used the following code to get the desired output set:

```
unique_string_parents = {' '.join(map(str, set(map(my_dict.get, sublist)))) for sublist in my_list}
# output: {'0 1 2', '0 1 3', '0 1 2 3', '1 2 3'}
```

Suppose I have a huge dimension of **my_list** and **my_dict** that can be found here: https://gitlab.com/Schrodinger168/practice/-/tree/master/practice_dictionary

Here is the code to read the real files:

```
import ast

file_list = 'list_array.txt' 
with open(file_list, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

my_list= [np.array(list(map(int, line.split()))) for line in lines]

file_dictionary = "dictionary_example.txt"
with open(file_dictionary, 'r') as file_dict:
    content = file_dict.read()

my_dict = ast.literal_eval(content)
```

I used a single line of code provided above; It takes about 16.70 seconds to get the desired output. I was wondering how I can speed up this algorithm or are there any other algorithms so that i can get the results faster in this case?

Any help or recommendation please! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code and `my_dict` I think you should use `np.array` instead of dictionary. Also, convert the numbers to strings at the end:

```py
# convert my_dict to np.array
arr = np.array([my_dict[i] for i in range(1, max(my_dict) + 1)])

# create the final set:
out = {frozenset(arr[l - 1]) for l in my_list}

# optionally, convert to string:
out = [" ".join(map(str, s)) for s in out]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['1 2 3', '0 1 3', '0 1 2', '0 1 2 3']
```

---

EDIT: With your files posted in the question you can try (On my machine this takes 11s vs 19s in original answer):

```py
import ast

file_list = "list_array.txt"
file_dictionary = "dictionary_example.txt"

with open(file_dictionary, "r") as file_dict:
    my_dict = ast.literal_eval(file_dict.read())

# convert keys back to string (to not convert the lines to int)
my_dict = {str(k): v for k, v in my_dict.items()}

out = set()
with open(file_list, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        out.add(frozenset(my_dict[i] for i in line.split()))

out = [" ".join(map(str, s)) for s in out]
print(out)
```

---

EDIT 2: Comparison of 2 methods:

```py
import ast
from timeit import timeit

# read sample data:

file_list = "list_array.txt"
file_dictionary = "dictionary_example.txt"

with open(file_dictionary, "r") as file_dict:
    my_dict = ast.literal_eval(file_dict.read())

my_list = []
with open(file_list, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        my_list.append(np.array(list(map(int, line.split()))))


def fn1(my_list, my_dict):
    arr = np.array([my_dict[i] for i in range(1, max(my_dict) + 1)])
    out = {frozenset(np.unique(arr[l - 1])) for l in my_list}
    return [" ".join(map(str, s)) for s in out]


def fn2(my_list, my_dict):
    out = {frozenset(np.unique(np.vectorize(my_dict.get)(l))) for l in my_list}
    return [" ".join(map(str, s)) for s in out]


assert len(fn1(my_list, my_dict)) == len(fn2(my_list, my_dict))

t1 = timeit("fn1(my_list, my_dict)", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("fn2(my_list, my_dict)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
1.7291587160434574
11.316183750052005
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your codes. It actually takes around 10.5 seconds. Do you have any alternative to even achieve this faster?

Comment: @Erwin I've posted another version, it seems faster than the first version.

Comment: @--Andrej Kesely The text file I provided is just to access to the real data. I don't want to read from it directly and perform the operation. I start to calculate the time when I got **my_dict** and **my_list**. The codes I provided is just to read the real data in order to get **my_dict** and **my_list**. The important step  to calculate the time when i get **my_dict** and **my_list**.

Comment: @Erwin I've updated my answer, comparing two methods. Seems the `fn1()` version is fastest (the key is to use `np.unique()`)

Comment: --@Andrej Kesely Thank you so much! this one seems to work the fastest in your case. I accepted the answer.